# Remove "figs." when using \cref

Tags: cross-referencing

When using `\cref{}` for cross-referencing multiple figures together, it automatically adds in "figs." beforehand. I've tried searching online for how to remove this, but can't find anything.

I've played around with `\renewcommand` but I'm not an expert with these things, so no progress there.

Alternatively, if it can be re-named to "Figs.", that would work too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want to generate a label "prefix" (such as "figs." or "Figs", simply use `\labelcref` instead of `\cref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want capitalized figure-name, you can use `\Cref` instead of `\cref`.
As requested, you can also redefine this figure-name.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{easyfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{}{}
\Crefname{figure}{}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \Figure[placement=h!, width=.5\linewidth, caption={Image A}, label={fig:A}]{example-image}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    \Figure[placement=h!, width=.5\linewidth, caption={Image a}, label={fig:a}]{example-image-a}
    
    \lipsum[3]
    \Figure[placement=h!, width=.5\linewidth, caption={Image b}, label={fig:b}]{example-image-b}
        
    \lipsum[4]
    
    \cref{fig:A} or \cref{fig:a,fig:b} or \cref{fig:A,fig:a,fig:b}.\par
    \Cref{fig:A} or \Cref{fig:a,fig:b} or \Cref{fig:A,fig:a,fig:b}.
    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple fix! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by

```
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref} 
\Crefname{figure}{fig.}{Fig.}
\Crefname{fig_a}{fig.}{Fig.}
\creflabelformat{fig_a}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1a)}#3}
\Crefname{fig_b}{fig.}{Fig.}
\creflabelformat{fig_b}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1b)}#3}
\Crefname{fig_c}{fig.}{Fig.}
\creflabelformat{fig_c}{#2{\color{NavyBlue}#1c)}#3}
```

Comment: Can you show how this answers the question (when referencing multiple figures together)? Why, for example, do you create 3 different reference types? And why bring `\color` into the mix?